# не могу импортировать библиотеку opendatasets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]хочу подключить дб из Kaggle, для этого надо импортнуть opendatasets
я скачал и через консоль, и непосредственно в юпитере
при импорта ошибка - `No module named 'opendatasets'`

```
!pip install opendatasets
import opendatasets
```

Comment: ну так установился модуль-то?

Comment: да, загрузка прошла полностью
но сделать импорт не удается
@Эникейщик

Comment: А `!pip install opendatasets` это в юпитере делали? Просто не может быть так, что ставили вы в одно окружение, а импорт делали из другого?

Comment: @CrazyElf дада, это буквально у меня в одной строке написано

Comment: Покажите всё-таки на всякий случай весь стек-трейс ошибки прямо в вопросе. Ну, мало ли что. Ну или хотя бы скриншот. А лучше и так и так. Странно это. И что писало при установке тоже покажите. И версию питона и ОС напишите.

Comment: @CrazyElf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/4y/99mqy6h170sc8fm66mc2tkyw0000gn/T/ipykernel_2479/136288107.py in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install opendatasets')
----> 2 import opendatasets as od

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opendatasets'

Comment: @CrazyElf Python 3.9.13, Mac 13.0.1, скрин ошибки в вопросе

Comment: Хм, странно. Либо это какой-то специфический прикол именно на Маке либо не знаю. Попробуйте на всякий случай установить с обновлением `pip install opendatasets --upgrade`. И ещё можно попробовать ядро юпитера перезапустить. Но вообще непонятно, да.

Comment: @CrazyElf не, не помогло, я и то и то сделала 
ошибка не поменялась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создать директорию
2. Открыть в ней консоль
3. Создать виртуальное окружение `python3 -m venv od-venv`
4. Войти в виртуальное окружение `source ./od-venv/bin/activate`
5. Установить библиотеку `pip install opendatasets --upgrade`
6. Создать файл `name_file.ipynb`
7. Импортировать библиотеку `import opendatasets as od`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]